Groups of order $p^3 q$, where $q \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, has a normal $q$-Sylow subgroup.

Show that a group of order $p^3q$ where $p$ and $q$ are odd primes and $q\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ has a normal $q$-Sylow subgroup

This is an exercise from Joseph Silverman's Abstract Algebra textbook. It is a fairly new textbook, and there are some interesting problems which I haven't been able to solve.
In the question, it is assumed that $p$ and $q$ are odd primes such that $q > p$, and there is a hint that states "you may need to use the fact that$-3$ is not a square modulo $q$".
My attempt: By straightforward application of Sylow's theorems, I get that the number of $q$-Sylow subgroups $n_q$ must divide $p^3$, and $n_q \equiv 1 \text{ (mod } q)$. But $q > p$ so $n_q \neq p$. Then $n_q = 1, p^2, p^3$. Can anyone help me eliminate the cases $n_q = p^2$ and $p^3$?

$p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)$. Can $q$ divide $(p-1)(p+1)$?

No it cannot, thank you for this. Where does the fact that $-3$ is not a quadratic residue mod $q$ come into the picture?

Not sure; if there were $p^3$ subgroups of order $q$, then $q$ divides $p^2+p+1$ and the Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal, that much is easy.

If $n_q = p^2$ then $p^2 \equiv 1 (mod q) \iff q | p^2-1 = (p-1)(p+1)$ and since $q$ is prime either $q | p-1$ or $q | p+1$ but both these cases cannot occur since $q>p$.
